# Recursive function with stack

Tags: recursion, assembly, stack, riscv

how can I use a nonpreserved register to be (n-1) indead of `n` while I do the recursion (line 26)? I have already tried to store in a different register but the result is wrong, any ideas?

```
main:
addi a0, zero, 7       # a1 = 7
jal function
j L

function:
addi sp, sp, -8 # save regs
sw a0, 4(sp)
sw ra, 0(sp)
addi t0, zero, 1 # temporary = 1
bgt a0, t0, else # if n>1, go to else
addi a0, zero, 1 # otherwise, return 1
addi sp, sp, 8 # restore sp
jr ra # return

else:
addi a0, a0, -1 # n = n − 1
jal function # recursive call
lw t1, 4(sp) # restore n into t1
lw ra, 0(sp) # restore ra
addi sp, sp, 8 # restore sp
add a0, t1, a0 # a0=(**n**)+factorial(n−1)   <---------- NEED to BE: a0=(**n-1**)+factorial(n−1)
jr ra # return
```

when I run the code, it will result of a0 to be 0x0000001c instead of 0x00000015. Because it iterates also the parameter that has been passed, when it should be -1. In other words if for example I pass 5 to the function, the result should be: 1+2+3+4 = 10 -> 0x0000000a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is `n-1` after the function call there are several options:

1. Recompute `n-1` starting from the memory saved `n` after the recursive call — so subtract one from `t1` before using it there — given how the code is already working, what could be simpler than computing `n-1` from `n` again?
2. However, you don't necessarily need to store `n` in function prologue — just reserve space for it there.
   Wait to store into the stack slot until `n-1` is computed and store that instead.  When you reload it, it will already have been adjusted by the -1 from the previous argument computation.  This way, the subtraction of 1 only happens once per recursive call.

---

A dumb compiler (or a compiler not in optimizing mode) would recompute `n-1` had that expression been repeated in the C code, as in `return n-1 + function(n-1)`.  `n-1` is said twice in source, so in a simple mode, the compiler will do it twice.

However, one could do the optimization oneself as in the following:

```
    int m = n-1;
    return m + function(m);
```

In that, `n` itself is no longer needed after the function, but `m` ***is***, so code for that will look like my option (2).

---

You can also get fancy and move the entire prologue to the `else:` section.  It won't save much overall but it is free to do that, so the base case won't need to allocate stack space at all (just that the base case not really on the critical path and shortening it will generally help but not as much as shortening the recursive case, depending on this function's average input value).  Just be sure to elide the equivalent stack restore in base case return.

---

Let's also note that the stack handling, computations, and variable save/restore would need to be exactly the same if `function:` were calling `function2:` instead of itself — in other words, it is the function calling that necessitates proper stack handling, and recursion adds no overhead or rules beyond regular function calling (as long as the system uses a call stack).